# get_post_meta is always results null

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get post meta description from my post in WordPress by calling get_post_meta but it always return null. I'm using Yoast SEO plugin for adding meta data in post. I'm trying this code to call my meta_desc on hook when post is publish first time.

```
get_post_meta( $post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true );
```

Is I'm doing wrong aur I have get it by another method.

Comment: Probably there is no value for this meta key and the given post-id. Check with phpmyadmin wether there is an value for your id - meta key pair.

Comment: I have checked, there is value present in the post meta table of wordpress for given post id.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct post_id.
Try printing $post_id to see if indeed correct id is being passed

Comment: <?php
$yoast_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true);
if ($yoast_meta) { 
    echo $yoast_meta;
}
?>